# What is setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(boolean) used for in UMP sdk?

Tags: java, android, admob, gdprconsentform

I don't know when should I put setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true) and setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false).
Should I use it with true if the user is underage? Then, all apps that implement UMP should be +18, right? I don't know if I have to ask the user if he is underage and then setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true)or setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false) always. I really don't understand the use of that method. How would the app determine the real age of the user?

This is where it is used:

```
    ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
            .Builder()
            .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(should I use false or true ?)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting#users_under_the_age_of_consent). It's specifically a setting for users in the EEA (European Economic Area) that helps with GDPR compliance - it sets a certain tag in your requests, which limits specific types of data usage by the ad requests and the ad vendors. There's a similar one in the section above (`setTagForChildDirectedTreatment`) which relates to California law. (They're not *true* or *false* booleans either, they're int constants - check the documentation!)

Basically, the idea is that if you're going to be displaying ads in your app, and providing data to app vendors, there are laws that you need to comply with depending on where the user is located - in this case related to the user's age. These settings allow you to configure ad requests in a way that *should** comply with those laws.

So it's up to you to do things like working out where the user is located (so you can comply with the legislation that covers them), and whether they're underage. Usually you do that by showing a splash screen that requires some kind of confirmation - a typical one is asking for their date of birth (you've probably run into that yourself!) so you can calculate their age and act accordingly.

The important thing is to confirm this before you send an ad request - don't assume they're an adult either, it's probably better to fall back to the safest configuration and only update it to *"above the age of consent"*, *"personalised ads allowed"* etc when you get confirmation. That way you're not breaking any laws before you realise you're not allowed to do that.

---

So you're relying on the user to tell the truth here, which is why you should make it a splash screen, something they can't dismiss - they have to make a declaration one way or the other. That's all you can really do.

But let me stress here, **this is only my interpretation of it**, and **this is definitely not legal advice**. You'll notice the language around all this stuff is about *helping you to comply* etc - there are no legal guarantees, and ultimately it's your responsibility to adhere to the appropriate legislation. Unfortunately that can lead to advice and *best practices* being a little vague or non-committal - it's rare to get any official *"do this and this and you're golden"* documentation, and you can end up with some stuff feeling unanswered. If you feel that way, it's not just you!

Comment: But that is very inefficient for developers, I mean you would have to check all the specific  laws of all the states of all the world. I mean, Admob already has a setting to set Max ad contet rating without the need of using any RequestConfiguration. Maybe it could be an option to use RequestConfiguration.setMaxAdContentRating if the user is in California for example ?

Comment: @pequeñaluna The burden of responsibility is ultimately put on developers, yeah. Things like UMP and services like Admob provide some functionality for you to use (like the method you're asking about) that helps simplify things, so there is a general workflow you're *supposed* to use. But crucially, they'll never say "this is all you need to do" or "if you do this your legal responsibilities will be met". You have to jump through a lot of hoops regarding data protection (especially if your app is available in GDPR countries) and it's not always clear if you're doing what you're supposed to

Comment: Basically, you can aim for the most restrictive settings, and then conditionally relax those restrictions if you believe the user qualifies - based on things like age, location, whether consent was given or isn't required, etc. There's stuff in UMP to help with that (like detecting if the user is in the EEU), for things like age you need to get a declaration from the user. With that information, you can configure your requests accordingly, using the functionality provided. Honestly you should probably look for some web articles about it, they'll be able to go into it in more depth

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your response, I have seen that               .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(boolean) in ConsentRequestParameters recieves a boolean. I have seen that if it is false, the form is shown, but if it is true, then it is not shown. I have thought that if the age of the user is < 18 years, use .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true) and else, use .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
. Could that be a good solution? Also, what does exactly .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true)? Maybe it is like a way to decline personalized ads  automatically if .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true) is used?

Comment: In the official Android UMP implementation I have seen the following:     // Set tag for underage of consent. Here false means users are not underage.

Comment: @pequeñaluna have a look at the link I posted - it's not for UMP but it explains what the tag is - it's a standard piece of data that's part of the ad request. Setting that should make every part of the chain act appropriately for a user that isn't old enough to provide consent for sharing their data - that's the idea anyway. It's different from a person just declining to give consent, which is why it's a separate bit of data you add. That's also why the form doesn't show up I expect - if the user *cannot give consent*, there's no reason to show a consent form

Comment: If you're talking about the example here (https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/ump/android/quick-start#request_the_latest_consent_information) I think the idea is you wouldn't hardcode `setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true)` or `false`, you'd determine their age (e.g. by asking for their date of birth) and then set that conditionally. You set up the whole "request consent" workflow as a general thing, but depending on stuff like that underage setting, the form may or may not get displayed, depending on the user's circumstances. It's been a while since I worked with this though